# Is it possible to prevent the start screen from covering the whole screen, making it more like the start menu?

Tags: windows-8, start-menu, start-screen

I'm getting used to the start screen, however it would be nice if I could stop it covering the entire screen and popup a bit like the old start menu.

Is there some configuration option, or program that enables me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a configuration option, but someone has already tried creating one using C#:
[How to Open Start Screen Within Desktop](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-open-start-screen-within-desktop/)

The direct download is here:
http://www.diablocrafts.com/uploads/SMModifier1b.zip

There is a discussion about it here: [Windows 8 Start Menu Modifier](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1104241-windows-8-start-menu-modifier/)

[image]

[image]